# AJAX to database sending null to PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm trying to use ajax to insert using a simple form into my database(using insert.php) to practice. Below the `var_dump($email)` is hitting null. The script runs through to here:

```
echo "Data for $name inserted successfully!";
```

The problem is the variables are null as stated.

So we make it to there, but the output is an empty variable field like below:

`Data for inserted successfully!`

Am I missing something here?

## index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The ajax/jquery stuff -->
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
//Get the input data using the post method when Push into mysql is clicked .. we pull it using the id fields of ID, Name and Email respectively...
$("#insert").click(function(){
//Get values of the input fields and store it into the variables.
var name=$("#name").val();
var email=$("#email").val();

//use the $.post() method to call insert.php file.. this is the ajax request
$.post('insert.php', {name: name, email: email},
function(data){
$("#message").html(data);
$("#message").hide();
$("#message").fadeIn(1500); //Fade in the data given by the insert.php file
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>Name: </label> <input id="name" type="text" />
<label>E-Mail: </label> <input id="email" type="text" />
</form>
<a id="insert" title="Insert Data" href="#">Push into mysql</a>
 <!-- For displaying a message -->

<div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## insert.php

```
 <?php
//Configure and Connect to the Databse
 include "db_conx.php";
 if (!$db_conx) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
 }
 //Pull data from home.php front-end page
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 echo "<pre>";
var_dump($email);
echo "</pre><br>";
 //Insert Data into mysql          INSERT INTO best_rate (name,email) 
$query= "INSERT INTO best_rate(name,email) VALUES('$name','$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$query);
if($query){
echo "Data for $name inserted successfully!";
}
else{ echo "An error occurred!"; }
?>
```

## UPDATE PHP #2

```
<?php
//Configure and Connect to the Databse
 include "db_conx.php";
 if (!$db_conx) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
 }
 //Pull data from home.php front-end page
 $name=$_POST['myname'];
 $email=$_POST['myemail'];
 echo "<pre>";
var_dump($email);
echo "</pre><br>";
 //Insert Data into mysql          INSERT INTO best_rate (name,email) 
$query= "INSERT INTO best_rate(name,email) VALUES('$name','$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$query);
if($query){
echo "Data for $name inserted successfully!";
}
else{ echo "An error occurred!"; }
?>
```

## HTML #2

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The ajax/jquery stuff -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Get the input data using the post method when Push into mysql is clicked .. we pull it using the id fields of ID, Name and Email respectively...
    $("#insert").click(function(){
    //Get values of the input fields and store it into the variables.
    var name=$("#name").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();

    //use the $.post() method to call insert.php file.. this is the ajax request
    $.post('insert.php', {myname: name, myemail: email},
    function(data){
    $("#message").html(data);
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#message").fadeIn(1500); //Fade in the data given by the insert.php file
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <label>Name: </label> <input id="name" type="text" name="myname"/>
    <label>E-Mail: </label><input id="email" type="text" name="myemail"/>
    </form>
    <a id="insert" title="Insert Data" href="#">Push into mysql</a>
     <!-- For displaying a message -->

    <div id="message"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

## Table Structure

```
===============================================
id | name | email
```

## db_conx.php

```
<?php
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Just for debugging, can use `GET` instead of `POST`. And then press `F12` if u r using Chrome browser and then go to Console. Click on the `Insert Data` link and check if the values are getting passed through ajax request.

Comment: @ℛⱥℐℰşℎ nope no data coming through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are having post method issue so we can use $.get instead of $.post and receive the data on $_GET["name"]

I think this is correct solution for now.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you havent gave name attribut to your feilds

```
<input id="name" type="text" />
```

use instead

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="myname"/>
```

and then used like this in your php file

```
$name=$_POST['myname'];
```

Comment: Still returning null values. Looking in firebug console I see post which shows 

`myemail 
d
myname 
d`

and

source is `myname=d&myemail=d`

Comment: echo these $name=$_POST['myname'];
 $email=$_POST['myemail'];

Comment: Echoed both. Nothing came through as in the success message.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and working correctly, as I can see there might be some issue with database connection or something mysql related. Your code working correct no need to give name or any other parameter in HTML as you have posted and given variable in jquery.

If you want more details you need to provide mysql related config file and table structure so I can check correctly.

Thanks

Comment: The form itself is sending blank rows so my assumption is that we're having no issue connecting, right?

Comment: I have checked and the data is correctly sending to the insert.php. I have checked on my local host and it's inserting data correctly with your code, so I am sure something with the database or connection related.

Comment: Okay I just uploaded table structure and db_conx.php

Comment: Hi Chris, I have checked and it's working fine. You can see my db structure

Comment: CREATE TABLE `best_rate` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
========================================================$db_conx=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

Comment: please check and confirm the db connection and it's pointing to correct database.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The database is receiving an empty row each time. It just has no values within the table from the `best_rate` table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75682/discussion-between-chris-and-pratap-patil).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2fwOeci.png, http://i.imgur.com/jTZz8Oy.png, these are the screenshots what value I am getting in ajax as well as in php file, so I am sure some issue with database pointer or something is missing, because code is correct and working correctly at my end.

Comment: This is what I'm getting `"INSERT INTO best_rate(name,email) VALUES('','')"`

Comment: I am available on private chat, can we have chat?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that the values from the inputs aren't getting passed to the php script to insert them.

I have noticed in your code that you pass an oject that contains these values:

```
$.post('insert.php', {myname: name, myemail: email},
```

I beleive that you are setting the name of the property (ie. myname) incorrectly. From my understanding,  the javascript is interpriting `myname` as a variable rather than a name. The correct code would be:

```
$.post('insert.php', {'myname': name, 'myemail': email},
```

This would then properly set the POST variables to use in your php code.

Comment: Changed this piece, but I'm still getting `"INSERT INTO best_rate(name,email) VALUES('','')"` as if they're still not coming through